# Kendo ui grid child add a row?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo Ui How to add rows to the table children.?

```
$("#ProcessTable ChildrenId?").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.add(obj);
```

In this way is it possible to add a new row?

Comment: What do you mean by "table children"?  Are you just asking if it's possible to add a new record to a Kendo Grid in code?  If so, then yes, that is possible.  Just reference the datasource of the grid and call the add method, passing in the new object.  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-add

Comment: When you mean "table children" are you referring detail template ?  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate